# jQuery $.post() JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, server-side

I have a JSON Object

```
{ 
    "widgetSettings":[{"maxDisplay": 6, "maxPerRow": 2}],
    "widgets": [
        {"wigetID": 1, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 1", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 2, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 2", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 3, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 3", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 4, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 4", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 5, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 5", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 6, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 6", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 7, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 7", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 8, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 8", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 9, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 9", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 10, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 10", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 11, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 11", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 12, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 12", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 13, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 13", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 14, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 14", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 15, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 15", "widgetColor": "defualt"},
        {"wigetID": 16, "show": false, "weight": 0, "widgetTitle": "Widget 16", "widgetColor": "defualt"} 
]}
```

I want to with jQuery to post that to a server side script so I can save it in a DB. And when I say save it I mean as the JSON object. However seeing as when you make a post/get other the way its posted is a JSON format my JSON that I am posting so I can save in the DB, gets lost it seems and the DB gets left with an empty value. Any ideas to what I may be doing wrong.. heres the jQuery portion.

```
$.post('ui-DashboardWidgetsPost.php', {"dashWidgets":dashboardJSON}, function(msg)
    {
        if(msg.error == "yes"){console.log('Error Found: '+ msg.errorMsg);}
        else
        {
        }
    });
```

***EDIT***
The PHP

```
<?php
$validJSON = $_POST['dashWidgets'];

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "", "") or die('{"error": "yes", "errormsg": "'.mysql_error().'"}');
mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die('{"error": "yes", "errormsg": "'.mysql_error().'"}');

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE dashboardPrefs SET widgetSettings='".$validJSON."' WHERE userID=100") 
or die('{"error": "yes", "errormsg": "'.mysql_error().'"}');

echo '{"error": "none"}';
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the PHP code on the server side, as well as the exact data that the server receives?

Comment: Is `dashboardJSON` a **string** (it has to be)? Maybe you have to assign that value to a key: `{data: dashboardJSON}` and then access the the POST `data` value.

Comment: Edited post to show PHP, and @Robus, I noticed that end of it just before I edited this :)

Comment: @chris: Try var_dump($_POST); on PHP side and alert(msg); on JS. See what you get. Also please see the edit I made to my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send the JSON (as string, not the actual values) to the DB, perhaps you should treat it as one?

```
$.post('ui-DashboardWidgetsPost.php', {
    json: dashboardJSON
}, function(msg) {
    msg=jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    if (msg.error == "yes") {
        console.log('Error Found: ' + msg.errorMsg);
    } else { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your server is parsing it properly?  The fact that it gets that far implies that the issue is in your PHP.

You're also best off also making sure that the data is moving across the wire properly, which you can do through the network tab of Chrome/Firebug.  That being said, I prefer to use an external packet sniffer like Fiddler (or HTTPScoop on the Mac).

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

1. Use the Javascript Object Method JSON.parse
2. Set That to a Certain POST value, we'll say "json"
3. Read it and decode on the server. With PHP, this would something like json_decode($_POST['json']).

Thus, the code on the client might be:

```
$.post('ui-DashboardWidgetsPost.php', 'json=' + JSON.parse(dashboardJSON), function(msg)
    {
        if(msg.error == "yes"){console.log('Error Found: '+ msg.errorMsg);}
        else
        {
        }
    });
```

And in PHP:

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($_POST['json'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `json` as the forth parameter.

```
$.post('ui-DashboardWidgetsPost.php', dashboardJSON, function(msg)
    {
        if(msg.error == "yes"){console.log('Error Found: '+ msg.errorMsg);}
        else
        {
        }
    }, 'json');
```